# +: expects type <number> as 2nd argument, given: #<void>;

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I'm currently working on exercise 1.29 of SICP, and my program keeps giving me the following error:

`+: expects type <number> as 2nd argument, given: #<void>; other arguments were: 970299/500000`

Here's the code I'm running using `racket`:

```
  (define (cube x)
    (* x x x))

  (define (integral2 f a b n)
    (define (get-mult k)
      (cond ((= k 0) 1)
            ((even? k) 4)
            (else 2)))
    (define (h b a n)
      (/ (- b a) n))
    (define (y f a b h k)
      (f (+ a (* k (h b a n)))))
    (define (iter f a b n k)
      (cond ((> n k)
             (+ (* (get-mult k)
                   (y f a b h k))
                (iter f a b n (+ k 1))))))
    (iter f a b n 0))

(integral2 cube 0 1 100)
```

I'm guessing the "2nd argument" is referring to the place where I add the current iteration and future iterations. However, I don't understand why that second argument isn't returning a number. Does anyone know how to remedy this error?

Comment: It's best if the code you present is self-contained, so you should include the definition of `cube` so your example is runnable.

Comment: h is a constant, and is define in a closure containing the value for a b and n that you want. your definition can be rewriten to use no arguments. y  only needs k, and iter needs only k and n. You've forgeoten the case where n=k in iter, and you've forgoten the (* (/ h 3) sum-terms) part of the algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing an `else` clause in your `iter` procedure. Ask yourself: what should happen when `(<= n k)` ? It's the base case of the recursion, and it must return a number, too!

```
(define (iter f a b n k)
  (cond ((> n k)
         (+ (* (get-mult k)
               (y f a b h k))
            (iter f a b n (+ k 1))))
        (else <???>))) ; return the appropriate value
```

Comment: Racket doesn't allow one-armed `if`s. You must provide an `else` expression (or use `when` if you intend it to be for-effect). This is good because it helps you catch mistakes. Unfortunately Racket does allow `cond`s without an `else`, and it doesn't help you catch that similar mistake.

Answer (score 5):

"2nd argument" refers to the second argument to `+`, which is the expression `(iter f a b n (+ k 1))`.  According to the error message, that expression is evaluating to void, rather than a meaningful value.  Why would that be the case?

Well, the entire body of `iter` is this `cond` expression:

```
(cond ((> n k)
       (+ (* (get-mult k)
             (y f a b h k))
          (iter f a b n (+ k 1)))))
```

Under what circumstances would this expression not evaluate to a number?  Well, what does this expression do?  It checks if `n` is greater than `k`, and in that case it returns the result of an addition, which should be a number.  But what if `n` is less than `k` or equal to `k`?  It still needs to return a number then, and right now it isn't.